# Authorization service design (application service)

Tags: authorization, domain-driven-design, access-control

I am looking for best architecture of authorization service, in application service layer, providing common authorization checks in services.

Ideally it should probably be single service, authorizing user to do actions on all aggregates. Things like browse lists, read/edit items, read/edit owned items, etc.

I am thinking about service with authorizing adaper for each agenda, reading solving by method on repository, but I feel I am reinventing the wheel. :-)

Have you any idea or good read/source?

Comment: You could implement something very sophisticated, but in the end I feel like having something as simple as `EntityXAuthorizationService`, `EntityYAuthorizationService` with methods such as `canDoX`, `canDoY` and `assertCanDoX` and `assertCanDoY` is very simple and can abstract away all the complexity of underlying implementations, like using ACLs, permissions & roles, rule-based logic, etc. Every method can have it's own signature so that the proper authorization context information can be provided.

Comment: The main downside is that you cannot enforce rules dynamically in a generic way (e.g. interceptor) so you must have checks in all your application service methods. However, you will never have to fight any security model abstraction limitations since you can do whatever you want behind these method calls and you authorization services can be injected with all the collaborators they need.

Comment: @voiceofunreason Any input?

Comment: Being familiar with asp.net core I would suggest that you take a look at [IdentityServer](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/index.html) as authentication service and [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) as authorization service.

Comment: @plalx This is how I am doing it now. I like it, but if I saw smart way how to do it better, I am open to adopt it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is externalized dynamic authorization also known as attribute-based access control (ABAC). In ABAC, there is an architecture which defines a generic authorization service which you can query to obtain authorization decisions (Permit/Deny) based off of policies (typically written in [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa)) and attributes such as user role, clearance, data sensitivity, etc...

NIST, the National Institute for Standards and Technology, has a great write-up on ABAC: https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-162/final

Comment: Nice article, thank you. I am talking about in-app, let's say domain-level authorization checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Keycloak, an open source tool for identity and access management:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html

Comment: Nice article, thank you (too). I am talking about in-app, let's say domain-level authorization checks.

Comment: Well I think that according to best practices, authorization should be done at application level, saying which user roles are allowed to run every use case (application service). I never did authorization at domain level, so I cannot help you. Sorry.